# c++ function not catching vector subscript out of range execption

Tags: c++, exception, c++14, outofrangeexception

I am trying to split a string on the char ":" then see if index 2 exists. My split string function works good as ive been using it for quite some time, but after trying to try{} catch() this it doesnt catch the execption and instead displays a debug error on my screen.

```
    std::vector<std::string> index = split_string(random_stringgg);

    std::cout << index[1] << std::endl;

    try {
        std::string test = index[2];   
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "error occured" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    std::cout << "no error";
```

To my knowledge, this should try to find the 2nd index of the vector "index" then catch the execption if it doesnt/cant find it. However, this does not work for me and instead just throws a "vector subscript out of range" even after adding the try/catch.
My question is why is it not catching and still displaying the error?

Comment: Why not just use `index.size()`?

Comment: *I am trying to split a string on the char ":" then see if index 2 exists.* -- You really shouldn't need to use exceptions for something like this, unless `random_stringgg` had guarantees about what it contains, and for some reason, the guarantee wasn't met.  Just use `size()` and check the result.

Comment: Hint: It's probably not actually throwing an exception

Comment: i do need to do this, i have to figure out what curl options i should be using and this is one of the ways i do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) does not perform any bounds checking, so it will not `throw` any exception if an invalid index is passed in.  Accessing an index out of bounds with `operator[]` is *undefined behavior* (the OS *may* raise its own exception if the invalid index causes invalid memory to be accessed, but you can't use `catch` to handle OS errors, unless your compiler implements a non-standard extension for `catch` to allow that).

If you want an exception to be thrown, [`std::vector::at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) performs bounds checking.  It will `throw` a [`std::out_of_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception if an invalid index is passed in.

```cpp
try {
    std::string test = index.at(2);
}
catch (const std::exception &e) {
    std::cout << "error occured: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `index` contains less than two elements, then `index[2]` invokes undefined behavior, meaning that the compiler can do whatever it wants.  Specifically, it is not required to throw an exception.  If you want an exception, use `index.at(2)` instead, which is specified to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to throw an out-of-range exception, you need to use `std::vector::at()` instead of `std::vector::operator[]`. But, you really should check the `size()` of the `std::vector`.